# snmpwalk failed with authorizationError

Tags: linux, snmp, net-snmp

I tried to execute:

```
snmpwalk -v 3 -u snmpv3username -A <passphrase> -a MD5 -l authNoPriv localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.334.72.1.1.6.2.1.0
```

However, I got the following error:
Error in packet.
Reason: authorizationError (access denied to that object)

I have already define the following in /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf:

```
createUser snmpv3username MD5 <passphrase> AES <passphrase>
```

Question is:
1. What is the meaning of this error? I thought I have defined the user in the config file
2. How to solve this issue?

If I execute:

```
snmpwalk -v 1 -c public -O e 127.0.0.1
```

I got this result:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux ip-10-251-138-141 2.6.32-358.14.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jun 17 15:54:20 EDT 2013 x86_64
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10 DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (615023) 1:42:30.23
SNMPv2-MIB::sysContact.0 = STRING: Root <root@localhost>
SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: ip-10-251-138-141
SNMPv2-MIB::sysLocation.0 = STRING: aws-west
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORLastChange.0 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.1 = OID: SNMP-MPD-MIB::snmpMPDMIBObjects.3.1.1
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.2 = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmMIBCompliance
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.3 = OID: SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpFrameworkMIBCompliance
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.4 = OID: SNMPv2-MIB::snmpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.5 = OID: TCP-MIB::tcpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.6 = OID: IP-MIB::ip
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.7 = OID: UDP-MIB::udpMIB
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORID.8 = OID: SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB::vacmBasicGroup
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.1 = STRING: The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.2 = STRING: The MIB for Message Processing and Dispatching.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.3 = STRING: The SNMP Management Architecture MIB.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.4 = STRING: The MIB module for SNMPv2 entities
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.5 = STRING: The MIB module for managing TCP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.6 = STRING: The MIB module for managing IP and ICMP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.7 = STRING: The MIB module for managing UDP implementations
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORDescr.8 = STRING: View-based Access Control Model for SNMP.
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.1 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.2 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.3 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.4 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.5 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.6 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.7 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
SNMPv2-MIB::sysORUpTime.8 = Timeticks: (2) 0:00:00.02
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemUptime.0 = Timeticks: (562693901) 65 days, 3:02:19.01
End of MIB
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

You do the snmpwalk with seclevel authnopriv but your user has seclevel authpriv configured.
Try:

`snmpwalk -v 3 -u snmpv3username -A <passphrase> -a MD5 -x AES -X <passphrase> -l authNoPriv localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.334.72.1.1.6.2.1.0`

Comment: I think you mean `-l authPriv`

Comment: And just because you have an encryption key in the createUser line, it doesn't actually mean than its required...  the VACM config would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Besides creating the user, you must also "authorize" it to see data.  Users can exist without any permissions to see data (its part of the SNMPv3 specifications).

For Net-SNMP, you can do this easily by granting it read-only access using this line in your `snmpd.conf` file:

```
rouser snmpv3username
```

or for write access to everything:

```
rwuser snmpv3username
```

**Edit:** Additionally, you should put the create user line in `/var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf` instead so it gets replaced by a private, localized key that can't be stolen and used in other devices.